# Failing to get certificate with Traefik from Lets Encrypt

Tags: docker, https, ssl-certificate, traefik, lets-encrypt

I am trying to get a certificate for my docker container but I keep getting errors, below is my docker-compose.  This used to work before until i deleted the container to restart it again.  I am using Traefik as the proxy and I am using it to request for certificates.

and I keep getting this error when i start my container to get the certitifcates.

Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains "mydomain.com": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [mydomain.com]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[mydomain.com] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized ::
Cannot negotiate ALPN protocol "acme-tls/1" for tls-alpn-01 challenge\n",
"providerName": "myresolver.acme"

Please note i have replaced the actual domain with mydomain.com and other lines of images in the docker compose have been left out for brevity.   Is there any rule i am not following properly?

````
services:

  ##Reverse Proxy
  traefik:
    image: library/traefik:v2.6.0
    container_name: traefik
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=false
    command:
      - --api.insecure=false
      - --providers.docker
      #
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entryPoints.websecure.forwardedHeaders.insecure
      - --entryPoints.web.forwardedHeaders.insecure
      #
      # ...
      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=email@email.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      # used during the challenge
      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web
      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json
      
      #logs
      # Writing Logs to a File
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --log.filePath=/logs/traefik.log
      - --log.format=json
      ## Access Logs
      - --accesslog=true
    networks:
      - traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./logs/traefik/:/logs/
      - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer:latest
    container_name: portainer
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - traefik
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./portainer-data:/data
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.priority=1"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`mydomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
networks:
  traefik:
    name: traefik```
````

Comment: Looking at the same problem here.